# Feature 'tslib' was enabled, but the pre-condition 'libs.tslib' failed (Qt5 cross-compile)

Tags: qt5, embedded-linux, cross-compiling, configure, tslib

I cross-compiled Qt5.12.11 for arm without the tslib support, and it was successful.
Now, I need to add the tslib support. I have the tslib already cross-compiled for my target architecture. I add the -tslib to my configure in this way, specifying the include and lib path with -I and -L:

```
./configure -opensource -confirm-license -xplatform arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-g++ -prefix myInstallDir/ -no-opengl -no-pch -I /path/to/tslib/include/ -L /path/to/tslib/lib/ -tslib
```

In the configure.log I can see the following:

```
loaded result for library config.qtbase_gui.libraries.tslib
Trying source 0 (type inline) of library tslib ...
None of [libts.so libts.a] found in [] and global paths.
  => source produced no result.
test config.qtbase_gui.libraries.tslib FAILED
```

I tryied to add in my qtbase/mkspecs/arm-cortex_a8-linux-gnueabi-g++/qmake.conf the following lines:

```
QMAKE_INCDIR +=  /path/to/tslib/include/
QMAKE_LIBDIR +=  /path/to/tslib/lib/
```

without any success.
I also tryied to add /path/to/tslib/lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment path, but nothing changes.
is it a problem related to the localization of the tslib lib & include paths?
can anyone give me a suggestion please?
Thank you.